# Como puedo hacer una multiplicación de matrices con este código , donde se abre el tercer archivo y se cierra?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
int main(){
    FILE *archivo, *archivo2,*archivo3;
    int i,j,k;
    int l,m,n;
    int mul1=0;
    int mul2=0;
    int mul3=0;
    int sum=0;

    int  temporal = 0 ;
    archivo=fopen("tarea.txt","r");

    fscanf(archivo,"%d%d%d%d%d%d",&i,&j,&k,&l,&m,&n);
    printf("%d %d %d\n%d %d %d\n",i,j,k,l,m,n);

    fclose(archivo);

    archivo2=fopen("tarea2.txt","w");

    mul1=2*3*5;
    mul2=6*7*8;

    fscanf(archivo2,"%d\n,%d\n",&mul1,&mul2);
    fprintf(archivo2,"La primera multiplicacion es:%d\n, la segunda es:%d\n",mul1,mul2);

    fclose(archivo2);

    archivo3=fopen("tarea2.txt","w");
    //the matrix is
    //2 3 5 
    //6 7 8
    mul1=2*3*5;
    mul2=6*7*8;

    mul3=mul1*mul2;

    fscanf(archivo3,"%d\n,%d\n,%d\n",&mul1,&mul2,&mul3);
    fprintf(archivo3,"La primera multiplicacion es:%d\n, la segunda es:%d\n,y la multiplicacion de ambas es %d",mul1,mul2,mul3);
    fclose(archivo3);
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué haces `fscanf` en un archivo que abriste en modo de escritura?

Comment: para escanear la informacion que hay en el archivo

Comment: Entonces, ¿Cuál es el objetivo de hacer todos los calculos si estás sobreescribiendo los resultados?

Comment: La cabecera `<string>` es de [tag:c++] ¿no será que querías usar la cabecera `<string.h>` que es de [tag:c]?

Comment: Y una pregunta más, ¿Desde cuando las matrices se multiplican así? no hay una sola operación de matrices que implique multiplicar todos los elementos de una misma fila... ¿Qué es lo que pretendes realmente?